# Замена ссылки htacces

Tags: .htaccess, apache

есть код:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/templates/main.html [L]
```

получается, что все запросы идут на файл main.html,
но нужно, например, ещё одно условие, которое позволит обращаться к файлу getdata.php как getdata, то есть нужно подменить ссылку

вот так не работает

```
RewriteRule ^getdata.php getdata [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/getdata.php
RewriteRule . getdata [L]
```

**Update**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/getdata.php
RewriteRule . getdata [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/getdata
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/templates/main.html [L]
```

Comment: при этом нужно оставить `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/templates/main.html [L]`.. не работает

Comment: @ast добавил в апдейт.